# Разархивация без замены

Tags: python, zip

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mainPath):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.zip'):
                archive = zipfile.ZipFile(root + '\\' + file)
                archiveFiles = archive.namelist()
                for archiveFile in archiveFiles:
                    if not os.path.exists(savePath): os.makedirs(savePath)
                    if archiveFile.endswith('.xml'):
                            try:
                                archive.extract(archiveFile, savePath + '\\')
                            except Exception as e:
                                print('error:\t' + str(e))
```

Реализовал разархивацию по каталогу, но проблема в том, что если разархивируемый файл существует, то он просто перезаписывается. А надо, чтобы файл переименовывался, например, как в винде. То есть если есть файл document, то если разархивируется такой же, то его имя становится document(1)/document(2)/... и первый не заменяется

Пытался поиграться с параметрами zipfile - не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Я немного подумал, и вот что у меня получилось. Надеюсь у меня получилось то что вам нужно.

> Тестировал на **Linux**, на **Windows** не проверял.

```
import zipfile, os, tempfile, shutil

file_zip = "путь/архив.zip"; # zip файл
path_to_extract = "путь";    # путь куда нужно извлечь
tmp = tempfile.gettempdir();
is_exist = False;

if (zipfile.is_zipfile(file_zip)):
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(file_zip, 'r');
    folder_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_zip))[0];
    for archive_file in archive.namelist():
        if os.path.exists(archive_file):
            is_exist = True; archive.extract(archive_file, os.path.join(tmp, folder_name));
        else: archive.extract(archive_file, os.path.join(tmp, path_to_extract));
    if is_exist:
        new_name = folder_name + "(copy)";
        while 1:
            new_dir = os.path.join(path_to_extract, new_name);
            if os.path.exists(new_dir): new_name = new_name + "(copy)";
            else: shutil.move(os.path.join(tmp, folder_name), new_dir); break;
    archive.close();
else: print "error: 404";
```